# PHP: loop trought array and create li list with array elements - array in array

Tags: php

I have an an array with objects:

```
Array ( [0] => 479,1,sometext [1] => 474,2,again text [2] => 472,3,and text )
```

The objects in array can be unlimited, but each object consists of 3 parts delimited by comma .

The result should be (in my example)- CORRECTED secondly

```
<li>
<span class="somecrap">array[0][0]</span>
<input type="text" class="secondcrap" value="array[0][1]"/>
<textarea class="3crap">array[0][2]</textarea>
</li>
<li>
<span class="somecrap">array[1][0]</span>
<input type="text" class="secondcrap" value="array[1][1]"/>
<textarea class="3crap">array[1][2]</textarea>
</li>
<li>
<span class="somecrap">array[2][0]</span>
<input type="text" class="secondcrap" value="array[2][1]"/>
<textarea class="3crap">array[2][2]</textarea>
</li>
```

etc.... depending of the count of the array objects

How would you accomplish this?

Comment: There is a corrected version of the result example. A bit more dificult.

Comment: I edited my answer to accommodate that - not too difficult

Comment: The results are corrected again, becouse Sam Dufel are so smart about arrays and gives for me too good solutions :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach($array as $entry) {
    echo "<li>\n";
    $elements = explode(',', $entry, 3);
    echo "<span class='somecrap'>{$elements[0]}</span>\n";
    echo "<input type='text' class='secondcrap' value='{$elements[1]}'/>\n";
    echo "<textarea class='3crap'>{$elements[2]}</textarea>\n";
    echo "</li>\n";
}
```

Updated to reflect your edited requirements. Untested.

Comment: You have a speed as a rocket :) Anyway, I corrected my example of results. The trick is, tat every span has its own Id.

Comment: jam: Should the id/class names be the same for every `<span>`? Or do you want it to be dependent on the content of each array entry?

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($arr as $row) {
    echo '<li><span>', join('</span><span>', explode(',', $row, 3)), '</span></li>';
}
```

Comment: +1 You might want to add the limit parameter for `explode` to limit the result to at most 3 parts.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$array = //Your input
$fieldNames = array('crap', 'someCrap', '3rdCrap');

foreach ($array as $row) {
  $fields = explode(',', $row);
  echo "<li>";
  for($i = 0; $i < 3; ++$i) {
    echo "<span class='{$fieldNames[$i]}'>";
    if(isset($fields[$i]))
      echo $fields[$i];
    echo "</span>";
  }
  echo "</li>";
}
?>
```

^^ Edited for your new requirements

Comment: You have a  speed as a rocket :) Anyway, I corrected my example of results. The trick is, tat every span has its own Id.

Comment: Wow. You are born with php arrays in your mind :)  What do you say about the new example of results?

Answer (score 0):

Your array is not 2D, it should look like that:

```
 Array (
   [0] => Array( [0] => 479, [1] => 1, [2] => sometext),
   [1] => Array([0] >= 474, [1] => 2, [2] => again text),
   [2] => Array([0] => 472, [1] => 3, [2] => and text)
  )
```

After that, it's just a matter of nested foreach:

```
foreach($myArray as $level_one){
 echo '<li>';
 foreach($level_one as $item){
   echo '<span>' . $item . '</span>';
 }
 echo '</li>';
}
```